# Finding files by relative path in sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am trying out Sublime Text as my new editor and I ran into an rather unexpected problem. I am working with a project (Django web app) that has many files with the same name sitting in different directories. So, I would have app1/models.py, app2/models.py ... app15/models.py etc. So if I just hit Cmd-P and type models.py I get a fairly sizable list that I have to scroll through to get to the file I want. In Vim, I just type `:e a`, hit TAB to complete the path, then once I have the right app, I type `mo` hit tab again and I am there. How do I do something similar in Sublime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a package on [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/) that would provide this sort of behaviour, but Sublime has nothing like that straight out of the box.

Since you've mentioned that you're new to Sublime, you may not realize that the panel that you're using is perhaps more powerful and useful than you think it is.

In particular, you're not constrained to typing full file names or paths in the box, and instead you can type fragments of filenames as well in order to filter the list down.

For example, this code base has roughly 4,000 files in it and I want to open a file named `Reader.h` from the folder `DevSrc/RegionalCenter/TSE/`. As you've noticed, you can filter the list with a name; say I do that here:

[image: Example 1]

Sadly for me, it turns out that the file that I want happens to be the last one in the list, which would require some scrolling to hit the correct file.

In this case, I know I want the file from the `TSE` folder, so I can just enter that partial path fragment before the name of the file I want, which constrains the list and brings the file I want to the top right off the bat:

[image: Example 2]

If you examine the results in the panel as they appear, you can see that some text in the matches is highlighted, telling you how the match is being applied.

That indicates that you don't actually have to type full file names at all; just any text will work and the best matches jump to the top. So here I can easily find the `Reader.h` in the `SIAC` folder or the `TSE` folder even more simply:

[image: Example 3]

Something to note here is that along with all of the internal criteria that Sublime uses to determine what files match, your previous choices are also taken into consideration.

In this case when I enter `tread` the `Reader.h` file jumps to the top; if I actually wanted the `Reader.m` file instead, I could add an `m` to the text to select it.

On the other hand, if I arrow down once and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the file, the next time I perform the same search with the same text, the `Reader.m` jumps to the top of the list because I've told Sublime what file I want when I enter `tread`.

As seen in the second example you can enter multiple space separated terms and have them match (e.g. `tse reader.h`). If you're using at least Sublime build 3154 (which at the current time requires you to be a licensed user because it's a development release), the terms in the panel can be in any order and still match.

This means that I could enter `reader.h` to get the list I want, then enter `tse` second to provide even more filtering, which is even faster and doesn't require you to know before you start what the full path is.

This just scratches the surface of the power of the Goto Anything panel; something to try would be the search terms `models.py@`, `models.py#` or `models.py:10`, for example.

For more information you can check out the [unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/) on [file navigation in Sublime](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_navigation.html).

Comment: Awesome answer. I did not realize I could type multiple words into that thing